# Are all homomorphisms proper?

Tags: coq

Is a homomorphism between two groups proper? Here are my definitions for groups and homomorphisms:

```
Definition associative {ty : Type} (f : ty -> ty -> ty) (eq : ty -> ty -> Prop) := 
  forall a b c, eq (f (f a b) c) (f a (f b c)).

Definition identity {ty : Type} (f : ty -> ty -> ty) (eq : ty -> ty -> Prop) (e : ty) :=
  forall a, eq (f a e) a /\ eq (f e a) a.

Definition op_inverse {ty : Type} (f : ty -> ty -> ty) (eq : ty -> ty -> Prop) (e a a' : ty) :=
  eq (f a a') e /\ eq (f a' a) e.

Definition op_invertible {ty : Type} (f : ty -> ty -> ty) (eq : ty -> ty -> Prop) (e : ty) :=
  forall a, exists a', op_inverse f eq e a a'.

Record Group : Type := Group'
  { ty :> Type
  ; op : ty -> ty -> ty
  ; eqr : ty -> ty -> Prop
  ; e : ty
  ; eq_rel :> Equivalence eqr
  ; prop_op :> Proper (eqr ==> eqr ==> eqr) op
  ; assoc_op : associative op eqr
  ; id_op : identity op eqr e
  ; inv_op : op_invertible op eqr e
  }.

Notation "A <.> B" := ((op _) A B) (at level 50).
Notation "A =.= B" := ((eqr _) A B) (at level 50).

Definition homomorphism {G H : Group} (f : G -> H) := 
  forall x y, f (x <.> y) =.= (f x <.> f y).
```

I want to prove:

```
Lemma homo_is_proper : forall {G H : Group} (f : ty G -> ty H),
  homomorphism f -> Proper (eqr G ==> eqr H) f.
```

Is this necessarily true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true.

Let `H` be a non-trivial group (e.g., `Z/2Z`), define `G` as the quotient of `H` under the total relation `eqr := fun _ _ => True` (`G` is thus isomorphic to the trivial group), and `f : ty G -> ty H` is the identity function. `f` satisfies `homomorphism`  but it's not proper.

In general, to reflect common mathematical practice, when working with setoids, properness is a basic fact that must be proved from first principles, and that the rest of a theory rests upon. Arguably, `homo_is_proper` is not a natural question to ask, because all theorems and properties (such as `homomorphism`) should really be parameterized only by proper functions in the first place.